# Setting Up a Node.js Application on HostGator VPS with cPanel and PM2

Tags: node.js, cpanel, vps, pm2

I created a basic Node.js application and purchased a HostGator VPS with WHM. From the VPS, I installed Node.js, Apache, and other necessary components. In cPanel, I set up version 12 of Node.js and used PM2 to run the Node.js application. Additionally, I created the application from the Application Manager, associated it with the primary domain, and appended "/nodejsapp" to the URL. I also specified the application path.

However, when attempting to make a GET request from Postman, it reports that the page was not found. Any ideas on what might be causing this issue?

This execution works fine, but when I try it from the production URL, it fails.

[image: respuesta correcta]

[image: APP MANAGER]

would like to be able to access the API I created from the production URL. However, when trying from Postman or the browser, it says: Page not found

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel Application Manager, you should follow this prerequisites before register the app : https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/